# Who's using the Justin TV API?

Tags: javascript, flash, api, video-streaming, justin.tv

We're looking at providing some live peer to peer video in sections of our site and have been playing with the API from Justin.TV for a couple of weeks now.  There are some alternatives like Ustream and Livestream, but JTV looks like the only free platform with an open API.

Development has been smooth for basic stuff like broadcasting and consuming video feeds and the price is right so I can't complain, but support is limited and there are not many developer resources when you get into the rest of the API.

There is lightweight API documentation here, with a few examples:

- http://www.justin.tv/p/api

There is a Google Group here, although activity is very limited:

- http://groups.google.com/group/justintv-api-developers

Is anyone else in the SO community using JTV?

Comment: You have seen the gallery, right? http://apiwiki.justin.tv/mediawiki/index.php/Application_Gallery I'm sure they've placed their largest users on that list already for publicity's sake.

Comment: I saw the gallery- the last posted example is from 15 months ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The end of the story is that Justin.tv closed off a major portion of their API today making it unsuitable for my purposes.

Further:

- Many of the entries in the gallery have been offline for weeks
- There is little to no activity on the Google group (above)
- There do not seem to be many (any) other developers on SO using it... a pretty telling sign.

I would advise anyone considering using JTV as an application platform to evaluate other options.